# Is there a way to make java.awt.Choice drop-down further?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have been searching around and haven't been able to find a way to make the Choice menu drop-down further. When I initialize and populate the component, it only shows eight options at a time after I click the drop-down arrow. Is there a way to make the Swing component Choice drop down further to display more than eight options at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether the **AWT** component `Choice` has an option to do that (I didn't find one during a short search).

But the **Swing** component `JComboBox` (the Swing equivalent for the AWT Choice component) definitely has a [`setMaximumRowCount(int count)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setMaximumRowCount-int-) method

Comment: Indeed! Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing. (Two reasons not mentioned there are that 1) people are more likely to know the answer for a Swing component, and 2) might actually care enough to answer.)

Comment: I switched over to JComboBox and it works much better than java.awt.Choice. I will definitely be using Swing instead of AWT in the future. Thanks!